# What is the effect of the neuralyzer on aliens?

Tags: men-in-black

In the *Men in Black* series (movies or comics), is it expected that an alien

- would lose its memory,
- nothing would happen,
- or have other side effects

if neuralyzed?

In the movies the MiB neuralyze entire cities, even knowing that there are different aliens among the population. It seems very unlikely to me that this device designed for human brains would have the same effect, or even be safe, on any other species.

Comment: Given that aliens live happily in the city, I would assume it can be tuned to 'human'

Comment: @Valorum But, the device only had three knobs, all targeting time duration.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 - Knobs can do lots of things. My watch only has one button and you can use it to set the time, start and stop a stopwatch and many other features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work on [bugs](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/Bug), according to Kay.

> *"Can you use the neuralyzer? Make him forget who he is?"*
>
> *"Doesn't work on bugs."*
>
> <sub><sup>[MIB: Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2010110.Men_In_Black)</sup></sub>

In the TV show, we see an [Arquillian](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/Arquilian) putting on a set of dark glasses in order to prevent being flashy-thinged.

[image]

Interestingly, this is contradicted a few seconds later. I think what Kay means is that it affects humans *and aliens with physiology that's similar to humans*.

> **Jay:** *Idea. We take your Neuralyzer, zap the next chowderhead we see, wipe all their memories clean. Hive mentality, see?*
>
> **Kay:** *Nice try. **Neuralyzers are designed to modify human memory cells.** [Scrawldians](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/Skraaldian) possess a different genetic makeup*